# How to make this type of data a node in neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, nodes

i want to make a node in neo4j from json data, named with the username(unique), and having as proprieties the created_time(int) and info(a list)

```
{
"ProfileInfo": {
    "created_time": 1286323200,
    "info": {
        "biography": "",
        "followers_count": 5000,
        "following_count": 1000,
        "full_name": "alpha beta",
        "id": 123456789,
        "is_business_account": true,
        "is_joined_recently": false,
        "is_private": false,
        "posts_count": 1,
    },
    "username": "alphabeta"
}
```

}

i tried to run this command in cypher:

```
Call apoc.load.json("file:/Neo4j/data/alpha_sample.json") YIELD value AS user
MERGE (u:USER {username:user.ProfileInfo.username})
SET u.created_time = user.ProfileInfo.created_time,
    u.info = user.ProfileInfo.info
```

but i get this error,

```
Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
```

Does anyone have any idea of how i can do this ?
any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to extract out each element in ProfileInfo.username. Does something like this help?

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:/Neo4j/data/alpha_sample.json") YIELD value AS user
MERGE (u:USER {username:user.ProfileInfo.username})
SET u.created_time = user.ProfileInfo.created_time,
    u += user.ProfileInfo.info
```